# Linux USB power limit

Tags: linux, laptop, usb

Is there a way to limit the current of a specific USB port to some value on a laptop running Linux? I have a mobile phone connected to my laptop, and I don't want it to draw a lot of power from the laptop, since I don't want my laptop to charge the phone (I am using it for data transfer and tethering). I want to limit the current to, for example, 100mA.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [In Windows, is it possible to manually select USB amperage output?](http://superuser.com/questions/834921/in-windows-is-it-possible-to-manually-select-usb-amperage-output)

Comment: Related but not a dupe. I am asking about Linux, not Windows.

Comment: There is a specification for each version of USB.  If a port is USB, it must meet the specification .  The specs include the amount of current that will be available.  A laptop can't offer "USB" ports that don't provide the prescribed power, and there is no type of user interface that allows you to reduce the available power output.  You would have to build your own current limiter in a dongle or find a way to stop the phone from charging.  BTW, the proposed duplicate question applies to Linux, also.  The OS plays no role.